# "has been opened " or "being opened"

Tags: present-perfect, progressive-aspect

> 1. The door of the refrigerator **being opened** by 90 degrees or less is closed automatically if you let go of the door.
> 2. The door of the refrigerator that **has been opened** by 90 degrees or less is closed automatically if you let go of the door.

I would like to know which sounds natural and correct. I think the second may imply as if the door was not able to be closed.

Comment: Neither: The refrigerator door closes automatically if you let go of it. There is no need to use the word open, it is implied since you can only let go of an open door and not a closed one.

Comment: I edited my question and added "by 90 degrees or less". How about my new question?

Comment: I wonder if you understood me: If you say: "let it go", **that means it is already open** and, therefore, you do not need to use the word open or opened. Also, it's refrigerator door, there is no need to be long winded and say: the door of the refrigerator.

Comment: The fact that the automatic door closure ***only works with the door open 90° or less*** is obviously both "relevant" and relatively "non-predictable". So I think it would be wise to explicitly call attention to this (and thereby help guide the reader towards a type of design feature he may not be familiar with) by rephrasing in such a way as to include the all-important word ***if***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is ungrammatical.  Just strike **being** and **by** and it's OK.

The second is grammatical.

You want to describe the actual *achieved* state of the door which triggers the automatic close.

> The refrigerator door (when) open|opened to 90 degrees or less closes automatically when you let go of it.

I think **open** is preferable to **opened** here.

Comment: Is the first sentence really *ungrammatical*?  It's so awkward that it certainly *sounds* like there must be some error, and I agree that OP should not use it, but if you parse it carefully it does make a certain kind of sense.

Comment: **being opened by 90 degrees or less** strikes me as ungrammatical. I meant to add **by** when suggesting the edit.

Comment: Wouldn't it be right to use the preposition at before  90 degrees?

Comment: @Rompey: The door itself may be **at** 90 degrees but it is **open to** 90 degrees.

Comment: I would prefer "The refrigerator door closes automatically if it's open less than 90 degrees".

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to modify the present progressive by the final state. The present progressive by its nature is discussing what is currently happening. What happens in the future (does or does not end up more than 90 degrees) is not a current state of the door. Does the door somehow know how far you're opening it, and if, as you're opening it, you intend to open it more than 90 degrees, then it doesn't automatically close?

Comment: @Accumulation: A door *in the process of being opened* does not close automatically when you let go of it. Rather, a door which is open [achieved state] will close automatically when you let go of it as long as it is has not been opened [achieved state] to more than 90 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

This would read better if you simply said:

> If you open the refrigerator door less than 90 degrees, it will automatically close when you let it go.

Using the expression "90 degrees or less" may be factually correct, but it is unnecessarily precise; using "less than 90 degrees" is sufficient. No-one is going to check that the door automatically closes at 89 degrees, but does not do so at 90 degrees.